# Апелляция к отклонению правки

Tags: поддержка, отклонённые-правки

Моя честно сделанная [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/260778) была не принята по некачественным причинам (из-за непонимания?). Хотел бы понять в чём дело или выяснить, где я в будущем могу обсуждать подобные вещи (если не здесь). Скрин правки прилагаю. Искренне считаю, что сообщение Eclipse в заговолке о наличии нескольких ошибок в строке не уместен.
[image: Правка]

P.S. Новая правка не отправляется по какой-то тех. причине.

Comment: Я б тоже отклонил...

Comment: Кстати, в сообщениях об отклонении есть целых две причины.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это уже настораживает. Почему? Серьёзно, поясните, зачем в заголовке сообщение "несколько ошибок в линии". Это никакой не текст ошибки

Comment: Проверяющие это "Боги на земле", они не всезнаюшие. Я бы тоже отклонил. По следующей причине: вы не дали точного описания в комментарии к правке, по какой причине вы посчитали этот фрагмент текста лишним. Ведь это из осталного содержимого вопроса не очевидно. Примите во внимание, что у проверяющего макс. 5 мин. на проверку и принятие решения.

Comment: @0xdb, простите. Уж склонен так и думать =) Да, неправ. И ещё не знал о ограничении. Взглянув на картинку приблизительно понятно, зачем это Eclipse пишет, на это и опирался.

Comment: Не нужно предлагать правки, меняющие один бессмысленный заголовок на другой. Тем более, когда в вопросе код картинкой и скорее всего его нужно вообще удалять. Правки должны улучшать вопрос (не формально, а фактически).

Comment: @Dmig, Просто не налегайте на правки сейчас. Предлагайте только действительно важные правки. Когда наберёте достаточно репутации, вы сможете вносить правки самостоятельно, без траты времени проверяющих.

Comment: Основная причина отклонения конкретно этой правки - общее качество вопроса от неё не возросло.

Comment: К слову, я бы отклонил и [следующую правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/260790). Потому как пока автор(или Вы?) не заменил картинки кодом - вопрос всё ещё бесполезен.

Comment: @vp_arth просто привык на некоторых сообществах постоянно что-то исправлять. Свою ошибку то я понял,но было бы лучше, если правку отклоняли по соответствующей причине (и уж точно не по заведомо неправильной). Насчёт `действительно важных правок` - тут уж как получится, я же не уверен, что проверяющие сочтут за важную правку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала проясню для окружающих важный факт, на который вы указали:

> сообщение Eclipse в заговолке о наличии нескольких ошибок в строке не уместен

...но который мало кем принят во внимание.

**"Multiple markers at this line" не является текстом ошибки**, а лишь сигнализирует, что в строке **несколько проблем**, и *уже после* него эти проблемы перечисляются. Толку от этого текста не больше, чем от "вылетает ошибка", он никак не характеризует проблему, а потому опознать ошибку и найти решение не поможет.

Да, я считаю что вы правы, убранная вами часть действительно бесполезна для вопроса.

---

Но как верно отмечено в комментариях, лучше от этого вопрос не стал. Он был безнадёжным и остался безнадёжным, и требует доработки **автором**, а не редакторами — вместо снимка экрана нужен **код текстом** и **тексты самих ошибок**.

А до этой доработки почти любые предлагаемые правки вопроса можно считать несущественными и отклонять. Посему, на мой взгляд, правку действительно следовало отклонить. Но **по другой причине**. Есть стандартная "не содержит никаких улучшений", которая, на мой взгляд, подходит гораздо лучше.

Если б ваши правки не требовали проверки (= если бы у вас было 2000 или более очков репутации), вряд ли у кого-либо возникли об этом вопросы. Особенно если бы вы **оставили комментарий** об этом. А пока вы ограничены *предлагаемыми* правками, ограничьтесь *существенными* улучшениями.

Answer (score 2):

В заголовке этому сообщению, пожалуй, действительно не место. Но проблема в том, что больше его нигде нет. Как уже сказали люди, отклонившие правку, найти вопрос по сообщению об ошибке после правки становится невозможно, поскольку сообщение только на скриншоте. Надо было не удалять, а переносить текст в вопрос.

Comment: Вы правда считаете эту строку текстом ошибки? А [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991482/5817214) миллионика с enSo (для Вас искал такую же проблему)? Зачем людям искать в поиске эту "ошибку"?

Comment: Хм.. Ладно, посмотрел внимательнее. Ok, это не текст ошибки.

Comment: Тем не менее на enSO есть такой вопрос и название этой "неошибки" у него в названии тоже есть ..

Comment: @Kromster, да, но я подумал (не запрещено, вроде), что нашему сообществу не нужен заговолок с этой записью Eclipse.

Comment: @Kromster, если это необходимо, могу создать вопрос с собственным ответом "Что значит ошибка "Multiple markers at this line"".

Comment: @Dmig если вопрос и ответ будут хорошими, то считайте что 2 моих плюса у вас в кармане (за вопрос и за ответ)

Comment: @Dmig хороший вариант. ТСу это решение напрямую не поможет, его интересуют ошибки в списке. Но иметь вопрос, поясняющий конкретно этот текст, может быть полезно.

Comment: @D-side, хорошо, сделаю. Однако, скажите, предполагается вопрос-ответ в стиле stanislav'а? 2 строки вход - 2 строки выход, да? (с картинкой)

Comment: @Dmig не вполне понял суть вопроса. Вы про то, что вопрос и ответ получатся почти тривиальные? Это нормально.